# Prevent people from marking question as duplicates with no experience in the technology

Tags: feature-request

I noticed that way too often a question gets wrongly marked as duplicate. That's a serious problem, because it prevents that the proper answer can be posted and it doesn't allow a discussion if it is truly a duplicate.

Just one example: [How to retrieve int value from datagrid (C# XAML WPF) - error 'System.NullReferenceException' [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875308/how-to-retrieve-int-value-from-datagrid-c-xaml-wpf-error-system-nullrefere)
 is a question about a WPF Datgrid. To answer it, one needs detailed WPF knowledge. As far as I can tell, the guys who marked the question wrongly as duplicate have no WPF knowledge. As a consequence, they think that a completely different, none WPF question about NullReferenceException is the same question. But that question gives general advice about this exception. People with experience in WPF could probably explain, why the error occurs, but they are now blocked from giving the correct answer.

Suggestion: Only people who have proven to possess expertise in the technology used in the question can mark it as duplicate. This could be done based on Tags used to mark the question and the tags for which the other users have high marks.

PS: How can the question above be "unduplicated" ?

Comment: _Prevent people from marking question as duplicates with no experience in the technology_ The vote that closed that question was from a gold badge user in that category.

Comment: How do you suggest we test whether people have or have not experience in the technology?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Gold badge doesn't mean he understands WPF. Someone with WPF could answer this question properly, but now he is unable to do so.

Comment: He got a score of 716 for his top Tag, but only 10 for WPF. I don't know what would be a good number, but it seems 10 is too low.

Comment: @PeterHuber _This could be done based on Tags used to mark the question_ The question was tagged with `c#` as well.

Comment: ...One of the users that closed it had a gold badge.  I'm really not sure what other mark of "experience" you're looking for.  Besides that, the OP needs to make a strong case as to why the question isn't a duplicate by either updating or adding more code, or explaining why they know their code isn't going to be null at a specific point (not knowing much about C#, in Java, if you attempt a cast of a boxable reference like `int` from `null`, you're going to get NPEs every time).

Comment: Would you allow someone who has 10 years experience in WPF, written books about it but has just joined Stack Overflow to vote to close such a post? Given their experience, you seem to say yes. However, the system has no way to know this, so would not allow it.

Comment: Extremely common tags like c# have to be filtered out.

Comment: @Oded agree completely, gold badges aren't always an indicator of experience but they're the best we have on putting some _measure_ on it, at least for this website. If we don't go based on gold badges in a category, what would you suggest @PeterHuber? also, filtering out common tags is no good, a lot of questions are only tagged with common tags.

Comment: @Peter As for the question: It is horrible and unlikely to be of any value. There's no [MCVE], and I don't see what's actually so WPF/XAML specific there. Most probably it's just the `SelectedValue` is `null` at the time the code is executed, and the problem could be simply solved by doing a check before accessing that.

Comment: @PeterHuber, seems like you're proposing some sort of AND condition on rep/badges instead of the OR condition we have now. Could you update your question to explicitly propose an algorithmic approach?

Comment: I have seen plenty of gold badge users marking questions wrongly as duplicate. In those cases, they did not care properly, what the question was about. Like in the question aboce, Null references can happen for millions of reasons. A general answer can impossible cover them an. But for a specific situation, a specific answer can be given.

Comment: @PeterHuber ah but that's the issue, SO isn't here just to help one person with this one issue, it's to help the OP and anyone else who has the same problem, the less likely anyone else will have that problem the less _value_ it holds on this website

Comment: Looks perfectly fine as a duplicate to me. Once the OP has worked out what's null, then the `NullReferenceException` is irrelevant - but the OP should take that first step themselves. The only times I regularly think that a `NullReferenceException` shouldn't be marked as a dupe of that (or the equivalent in the Java universe) is when the exception is deep in someone else's code. If it's just "I've dereferenced a null reference" then the right question is "Why is this reference null?" rather than "Why am I getting an exception?"

Comment: @user0042, It is very WPF specific to know when which value can be accessed or which value he should access instead. Just explaining in general what a null reference means is trivial. On the other hand, providing a working code for the question is valuable. I noticed this problem many time, that a question got marked as duplicate because it had a certain error message, without considering that the reason for the error and the solution was completely different.

Comment: @Peter As others already pointed out that wasn't in question there.

Comment: @user0042 The question was "How to retrieve int value from datagrid". The other answer was about how to prevent null references exceptions in general. It had a WPF example, which did not address "How to retrieve int value from datagrid". A working datagrid code would. I have spent 10 years (!) with WPF, and believe me, it can be terribly difficult to understand.

Comment: I just searched for "NullReferenceException" on SO. I got 15000 questions. Obviously, it doesn't make sense to mark them all as duplicates.

Comment: It's easier to understand when you know what a `NullReferenceException` is and what causes it though. That's what the duplicate gives. If the question had been written to ask why the value was null, it wouldn't have been closed - but it looks like the OP either doesn't know what a `NullReferenceException` is (in which case the duplicate is appropriate) or they do, but they couldn't be bothered to do the diagnostic work to make it a *good* question (in which case I have little sympathy). Neither case warrants a bad question remaining open, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Having to post a similar question again spams SO. Better is, if the question can be improved, which is not possible once it is marked as duplicate. Having said that, I don't see what is terribly wrong with the question title.

Comment: They don't have to post a similar question again. They can edit their question to indicate that the problem isn't the exception - the problem is the null value, which they should be able to identify specifically. (The problem with the question isn't with the title - it's with the lack of effort that's gone into the question.)

Comment: @JonSkeet My experience is that once a question is marked a duplicate, it is impossible to do anything, everything is blocked and nobody can answer. The only solution is to post a similar question again and explain why not a general answer is sought, but a solution for that specific problem.

Comment: @PeterHuber If they edit the question, it will go into the reopen queue, if I'm not mistaken. If they've edited it sufficiently to show that it isn't a duplicate, it can be reopened. This doesn't usually happen, but that's not the fault of the system. The opportunity is there.

Comment: @PeterHuber If *you* believe it is not duplicate you can edit the question to show why it is not duplicate as well as demonstrate research OP should have put there and provide good MCVE and vote to reopen if you can (such edit is frowned upon as it puts words into OP's mouth but making gem of ordinary post may worth it - even if edit is declined if OP likes the change they can accept it later). Note that keeping question of this kind open invites downvotes while if it is closed it way less likely to get attention needed for downvotes.

Answer (score 10):

I understand where you're coming from, and I also understand those who voted to close.

The asker experiences a `NullReferenceException` and asks how to fix it, the close voters point to the reference question for this type of problem.
However, the asker should be asking how to retrieve data from a `DataGrid`. The question title does kind of ask this, but the question body doesn't. For now, the question should remain closed. When (and if) the asker understands the current issue, they can edit their question with what they *should* have asked.

That being said, your suggestion to require proven experience for closing a question is not a good one. Plenty of people possess lots of knowledge on a certain technology without necessarily having "proof" of this on Stack Overflow, especially with so much information already being available on SO to be read, decreasing the need to post questions and answers.
Additionally, getting questions is hard enough as it is, and the occasional "false positive" does not warrant such a drastic measurement.

Comment: At the moment, I *don't* think the question should be reopened and closed. The first thing the OP should do is understand what causes a `NullReferenceException`. *They* can then work out what's null (in the normal way) and change the question so it's no longer about a `NullReferenceException`. *Then* it would make sense to reopen it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've made a ninja edit, changing "reopened" to "reopened and edited", and now just also swapped the order of the two.

Comment: My problem with that approach is that at that point, the OP will do exactly the same thing the next time, instead of doing the diagnostic work themselves to find out and then explain what's null. This way, the OP is channeled towards a question that will help them improve - and they can improve the question themselves.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair point, and I agree.

Comment: @Stijn My suggestion comes from a deep frustration over my own questions marked wrongly as duplicate. I usually spend a day before posting a question, but the gold user doesn't investigate the situation properly. If there is a better way to deal with it, like making it easier to resolve such disputes, I would be all for it.

Comment: @PeterHuber the question you linked to as an example does not look like one that someone spent a day composing. The better way to deal with it is to include more details of what you've done to try to solve the problem in the question to begin with. Then, if it really isn't a duplicate, that will be more apparent.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Exactly. The Question did not provide enough details. But most people asking on SO are not expert users and we should guide them how to improve their questions. Just blocking them will frustrate them and they give up.

Comment: @PeterHuber: They're not blocked. They can edit the question. Just because users can't *answer* the question doesn't stop them from *editing* the question.

Comment: @PeterHuber It is strange that you claim to have plenty of good examples of bad closure of your own well researched questions but instead you pick classical "here is small chunk of code with NRE - go fix it" post. (Not that it is going to make suggestion itself any more desirable, but it is harder to see problem when there is no real examples)

Answer (score -1):

I just asked nearly the same question as yours and I was informed by some user that my question is duplicate.

(The user who informed me even made a joke that he won't mark my question as duplicate because he don't want to do the same mistake I'm complaining about.)

I have seen the problem you are describing twice within the last 7 days in conjunction with `assembly`  language questions:

Unlike the case described in Stijn's answer, the questions marked as "duplicate" (in one of the two cases [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122039/what-are-the-meanings-of-callq-command-parameters) was marked as "duplicate" of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46752964/what-is-callq-instruction)) were asking something completely different and the only thing they had in common was the same keyword (`callq` in the example) in the question.

And the answers in the first question did also not answer the "duplicate" question in any way.

According to the user profile of the users having voted for closing the question, they neither ever asked `assembly` questions nor answered them, so I have to assume that those users did not understand the two questions correctly and therefore marked the questions as "duplicate".

For such cases I indeed see the need of:

- The possibility to write an answer to a "closed" question; maybe the answer should be hidden until the question is re-opened.
- At least some message which is displayed to users who vote for a question to be "duplicate" that they should first leave a comment if they are not 100% sure if the questioner does not ask for some aspect which has not been addressed in the already existing answer.

Answer (score -12):

Is this a problem: yes, but using a certification process whether it be by badges/rep/tags etc does not offer a good solution because all of those are things that indicate how much experience a person has on StackOverflow more than their speciality in an area.  Inversely, sometimes the best feedback you get comes from someone who does not know much about a specific technology, but instead has good insight into a processes that are similar between languages like functions, loops, etc.

I feel like a better solution would be *to require* an audit process whereby someone says "hey, this looks like a duplicate of this other thing", and that the OP should be the one to say whether or not that answers the question.  In the end, if something marked as duplicate but does not answer the question for the OP, then marking it as a duplicate isn't really helping.

Comment: We have the process you describe in the second paragraph, actually. That's just not the *only* way for something to be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm sorry I was unclear, my point is that it should be the only way.  While a person with enough reputation points can generally make unilateral decisions about closing a thread based on things like violating terms and conditions, allowing them to close someone's thread based on duplication without the OP's consideration opens up all sorts of problems.  When you've been programming for 10+ years it's easy to see step A and B and leap straight to step D believing step C will be understood to everyone, and these oversights are often the things that lead to "answered" questions being asked again.