# Avoiding questions being marked as "duplicate" of completely unrelated questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

In the last days I observed the following scenario multiple times on StackOverflow:

Two questions (about assembly language) were marked as "duplicate" of other questions, although the other questions were asking something completely different.

Unlike the scenario described in [the answer linked by user "Tom"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355670), **none** of the answers in the already existing questions answered a single aspect of the new question in any way.

However, I see two questions as "duplicate" when a complete, correct and detailed answer to one question also answers the second question.

... or at least if some answer posted to the original question already answers at least one aspect of the new question.

However, in the two cases from last week this was not the case:

In one case, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122039/what-are-the-meanings-of-callq-command-parameters), was marked as "duplicate" of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46752964/what-is-callq-instruction) before it has been re-opened.

Both questions had answers and the answers were answering the question and all its aspects correctly, completely and in detail.

However, the answers to one question did **not** answer any aspect of the other one.

For me this means that the two questions **cannot** have been "duplicates" because a complete, detailed answer to one question does not answer any aspect of the other question.

My assumption is that the user who voted for "close because duplicate" did not understand the question correctly.

I have to admit that the question was originally worded in a way that was not well-understandable. For this reason it might have been possible that the question was misunderstood and therefore has been marked as "duplicate".

On the other hand, the question was worded well enough that some user posted an answer that addressed the new question. So I doubt that the bad wording was the problem.

Question:

This happened twice in one week. Is it just coincident that this happened twice in a very short time or does this happen very frequently?

If this happens more frequently:

Would it make sense to change something on the StackExchange network to avoid such a scenario in the future?

(For example some notification to the voting user which is saying: "*Please only vote for close if you have ensured that the answers to all aspects of this question are already given in the other answers.*")

Comment: Related: [Prevent people from marking question as duplicates with no experience in the technology](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355670), but I don't know if it is a duplicate, I may just didn't understand this question.

Comment: @Tom I modified my question: The question you linked is not really addressing the problem I'm talking about.

Comment: Please don't take tag score on SO to judge if someone has knowledge in a technology or not. I, for example, only answer OpenGL questions on SO and have an almost 0 score in C#. But I've been developing mainly in C# for the last 5 years.

Comment: @BDL You are right. For this reason I don't think that an "automated way" (based on score or similar) to avoid this is possible. However, in the cases I observed it was absolutely obvious that the questions were marked as "duplicates" of questions which were **absolutely unrelated** to the questions asked! This is an indication that the users voting for close did **not** understand at least one of the two questions. And the fact that a correct answer was posted before the question was re-opened is an indication that the question was well understandable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would it make sense to change something on the StackExchange network to avoid such a scenario in the future?

I see no reason to make it more difficult to dupe-close a question. Incorrect duplicate closures are easily taken care of by the community, through the re-open mechanism. On more popular tags, there are gold badge owners that can single-handedly re-open a question where necessary.

Comment: Thanks for anwering. I re-worded my question completely: I'm talking about two cases in the last week where the two questions were **DEFINITELY** asking something completely different. And the answers that were already posted to the first question **DEFINIETELY** did not answer the new "duplicate" question! I'd like to know if this happens frequently or if it is just coincident that this happened twice in this week.

Comment: By writing "*that both questions were asked in a well-understandable way*" I want to say that some user having read both questions and the answers attentively must have noticed that the question was asking for a completely different aspect which was neither asked nor answered by the already existing question, yet.

Comment: By rewriting your question like that, you removed most of the context of my answer, invalidating my answer... Please don't do that. If you want to ask about two specific cases, then ask about two specific cases. Don't re-write a more general question.

Comment: Would it have been better to delete the question and re-write it completely?

Comment: If you changed your mind about what you're wanting to ask here, then yes. I've edited my answer to remove everything that no longer relates to the question... I hope you understand that re-writing questions like that is a waste of time for users that answered your question.